# how to get all the resources in an AWS account irrespective of the resource type

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3

I want to get all the resources in an AWS account irrespective of the resource type and region using python. So that i can see how many resources were created, when created e.t.c

How can i achieve this. I followed boto3 but i am unable to find  a way to get all resources.

I followed: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/resource-groups.html#ResourceGroups.Client.group_resources

Am able to get all instance using one service, am able to get all s3 at one service.. but i need all resources at a time irespective of resion or type

Please suggest me good way to achieve this at once.

If not, is there a way where i can pass all resource type in a list and pass it and get.

Answer (score 1):

If you have enabled AWS Config service, you can easily list all your resources.

[list_discovered_resources](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.9.88/reference/services/config.html#ConfigService.Client.list_discovered_resources): Only lists resources in the current account/region. That means you need to create a client in each region and merge the results.

You can also configure [multi-account multi-region data aggregation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/aggregate-data.html) to fetch resources from all your accounts. In this case, you can simply use [list_aggregate_discovered_resources](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.9.88/reference/services/config.html#ConfigService.Client.list_aggregate_discovered_resources) and filter resources by account and region.

Comment: Thanks.. will try this and let you know if I stuck some where

Comment: Hi @Vikyol, thanks for the path you suggested. But, its not listing all the resources. For ex: transcribe .it's not showing in the JSON response. Is there a way to get all resources used?